# 2019 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Joomla's [first moderator election](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/election/2) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the new moderator is:

[image: mickmackusa]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Also, please join me in thanking Harald Leithner who will be stepping down as moderator.

Since this is a [*pro tempore* election](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections), there was no need for it to be competitive. With only one nomination, we skipped the vote.

Answer (score 4):

Congrats @mickmackusa and welcome to the team!

We now have a nice balance in moderation between different timezones

Thank you to Harald for his time dedicated to making JSE a better place.

Answer (score 3):

Well done Mick and thanks for volunteering.

Thanks so much to Harald also for helping us get this far.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome mickmackausa to the team and a big thank you to Harald for all these years. @Mickmackusa let us know if you need any help.